# ContextMenu in Windows' upscale mode

Tags: c#, contextmenu, scale, menuitem, notifyicon

I create a context menu for NotifyIcon in the following way:

```
  _trayIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new[]
  {
    new MenuItem("About", About),
    new MenuItem("Autostart", autostart),
    new MenuItem("Skins", ContextMenuGetFromResFolder()),
    new MenuItem("Close", Close)
  });
```

When I increase the size of the GUI through the parameters of the screen, the text of the menu becomes blurred (unlike the menu text of other icons in the tray).

Other TrayIcon's ContextMenu (left) and my ContextMenu (right) in 125% GUI-scale:
[image: Other TrayIcon's ContextMenu (left) and my ContextMenu (right) in 125% GUI-scale]

The question is, why does this blur happen and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: The question is, why does this blur happen and how can I avoid it?